# Can I set Thread.CurrentThread.Name in Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am using following C# code to process request.

```
Parallel.ForEach(reqs, parallelOptions, req => ProcesRequest(req));
```

Inside ProcesRequest method can I set thread name. See following code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Some name with " + i;
```

Please suggest if above code will give consistent thread names.

Is it fine to write such code. And does it affect when lot of threads will get created?

Is there any reusing of threads happens internally?

Comment: "This property is write-once". Don't give names to threads you didn't explicitly create yourself -- you have no control over what `Parallel.ForEach` does.

Comment: Isn't it faster to try for yourself what happens when you do that?

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is using the thread pool. You "borrow" threads from the pool to do your work. Just as it would be rude to check into a hotel and scrawl your name on the door, it's also rude for code to act as if it owns something it's only borrowing.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: You are right!! I have already tried that. Is does not allow me to change the name. Getting following exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This property has already been set and cannot be modified. But this happens with main thread. Not for ProcessRequest method. Meaning inside ProcessRequest, I am able to change the name.

Comment: But even if you could - why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Evk: Various logger framework prints thread names. I want to leverage that features of logger. Hence I want to set thread name.

Comment: Any logger framework worth its salt will have something like a custom context class that can be used for this, like `log4net.ThreadContext`. If yours does not, you're still far better off being explicit about what you log, rather than relying on ambient properties -- even if they work they're prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use *Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId*

```
ParallelOptions pOpt = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
};

Parallel.ForEach(reqs, pOpt, req=> {
    string thName = "Thread#"  + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    Console.WriteLine(thName);
});
```